# Add shadow to text in ms word by vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on a template  in ms word , I need to add shadow to a selection.

The macro recorder gives

```
Selection.Font.Shadow = true
```

but I didn't know how to use it and how to determine the type of shadow and its properties.  I didn't find the name of these types or how to deal with them, like setting the depth or angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the macro recorder does not yield much information about working with "Text Effects"...

The `Shadow` property can only set whether a text effect shadow is "on" or "off".

To change how the shadow looks it's necessary to work with a `ShadowFormat` object. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shadowformat) for `ShadowFormat` is somewhat misleading since it refers only to `Shape` objects. But the same properties apply to shadows for fonts.

What's more, the property for returning a `ShadowFormat` object for a `Font` is not ShadowFormat, it's `TextShadow`. So code like the following example:

```
Sub AddFontShadow()
    Dim shad As Word.ShadowFormat

    Set shad = Selection.Font.TextShadow
    With shad
        Debug.Print "Blur: " & .Blur, _
                    "ForeColor: " & .ForeColor, _
                    "Obscured: " & .Obscured, _
                    "OffsetX: " & .OffsetX, _
                    "OffsetY: " & .OffsetY, _
                    "Style: " & .style, _
                    "Transparency: " & .Transparency, _
                    "Type: " & .Type
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the accepted answer:

```
    Set img = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=fn)
    img.ConvertToInlineShape
    With img.Shadow
        .Blur = 5
        .ForeColor = 0
        ' .Obscured = -2 (fails for negative number)
        .OffsetX = 0
        .OffsetY = 0
        .Style = 2
        .Transparency = 0.6
        .Type = 25
        .Visible = True
    End With
```